# jQuery loads external php file to a div but does not stay still after page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, refresh

When I click a link in my menu so I load a specific php page with content in a div named "adminPage" but does not stay still after page refresh?

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#page1').click(function(){
        jQuery('.adminPage').load('page1.php'
        );
    });

    jQuery('#page2').click(function(){
        jQuery('.adminPage').load('page2.php'
        );
    });
})


<ul class="menu-items">         
    <li class="link">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="page1">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Page 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="pag2">
             <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Page 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="adminPage"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the idea of [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

> With Ajax, web applications can send data to and retrieve from a
>   server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the
>   display and behavior of the existing page.

Using [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), you can push state into history.

Make sure that when you attempt to load http://example.com/page1.php, the page will be loaded.

Then, you can use something like this:

```
jQuery('#page1').click(function(){
    jQuery('.adminPage').load('page1.php', function() {
         var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
         history.pushState(stateObj, "page 1", "page1.php");
    });
});
```

Using `pushState`, the history entry will be updated, but your browser will not make request to `page1.php`.

---

<sup>1) [pushState: what exactly is the state object for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612307/pushstate-what-exactly-is-the-state-object-for)</sup>

Comment: there is no easy way to do it with jQuery?

Comment: I like this option, but when you reload the page, visible only to the loaded file and nothing else. this can change?

Comment: Well, you need to update your layout a bit. If `.adminPage` is content wrapper (incl. header, body, footer, etc.) it should works.

Comment: I can not just add a hase or ID?

Comment: What's the code of `page1.php`? You can use `pastebin` to share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery's hashchange plugin.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

The idea is onclick, just change the hash of the page.

And on `hashchange` event, load the content.

Even you refresh the page, get the hash and do the needful (loading of content etc...)

`Gmail` does it, for loading any page it changes hash.

And even after page refresh, the AJAX loaded content gets loaded.

Hence, your requirement gets fulfilled.

Comment: this sounds interesting, it is possible to implement with my script or do I do something else?

Comment: Just add jquery plugin with `<script>` tag and implement it. I have done it in my projects so I can say that implementing it is easy.