# Ho to remove a string from URL in ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string

In the below posts, I'm adding string `#show-post` to the current URL .I will have a simple function to trigger a pop up box when the string present in the URL. This is an alternative idea as `$(".posts-popup").trigger('click');` is not working oddly, its placed in the success function of ajax.

ANd this adds the string multiple time like this:

```
http://localhost/homepage.php#show-post#show-post#show-post#show-post#show-post#show-post#show-post#show-post#show-post#show-post#
```

ANd problem with adding the string to URL, each time the page is reloaded and the string is present, this pop up box function triggered. SO I'm looking for a way to remove the string from URL when other ajax calls are made.

```
window.location.href.split(/[?#]/)[0];//to remove the string.
```

I referred here: [Remove querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url)
I thought this would, immediately remove the string when I place this in the ajax success function, but it doesn't remove at all.How to use this then?

//string added in the success function of ajax

```
$("input[name^=delete2]").on("click",function()
    {

    var deleteMe = this.id;

    $.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: '/delete_this.php?id='+deleteMe,
    success: function(data){

      //$(".posts-popup").trigger('click');
     window.location = window.location.href + "#show-post";
     window.location.reload();

      }//end sucess
    });//end ajax

  });
```

Comment: When appending a new hash in URL, first check if URL already contains it. If not then only add it.

Comment: just set `window.location.hash`. Not totally clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @Tushar, I checked like this: success: function(data){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#show-post") != -1)
    {
     window.location = window.location.href + "#show-post";
     window.location.reload();
    }
   
  }//end sucess

Comment: @Tushar, but that prevent that main ajax function from happening and doesn't add string

Comment: @charlietfl Is right here to use `window.location.hash`, set the value to it.

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks, I've successfully added the string via hash..but how to remove the string from URL in other ajax success function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var state = { yourState: foo },                        
var newURL = window.location.pathname+"#show-post";
window.history.pushState( state , null, newURL);
```

Cheers

Comment: what whould be there in the var state ?

Comment: Check this previous answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612307/pushstate-what-exactly-is-the-state-object-for. Btw, I am not sure if I got your question correctly. If you want to remove the "#show-post" then use   var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '#' ); pathArray[0];

Comment: should note that older browsers don't support `history.pushstate`

Comment: oh i see, ill find some alternative for that

Comment: yes old browsers won't support it. But newer browsers, which use the html5 engine are supporting it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29