# Detect change of URL (NOT just hash) using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, window

I believe you know that some sites have built on "one-page system".

In such systems after clicking on the link the site do not moves user to another page but just reloads the page with Ajax and changes the URL.

I saw many answers about `$(window).on("hashchange")` and I know this trick, but I need to detect the WHOLE URL change (NOT just hash of it) – so I need something else.

Any ideas how to detect the whole URL change?

Comment: Wouldn't a change to the url other than the hash cause the page to reload?  Thus *NOT* a SPA?

Comment: I think you should consider using [$.unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/) as an alternative option

Comment: $.unload doesn't happens because the page actually doesn't "unloading" – only URL is changing. For example when I click on Play button on https://www.netflix.com/title/70178217 the page do not reloads - it just changes the url to https://www.netflix.com/watch/80049213

Comment: @Taplar nope. window.history.pushState() in html5 let you to change the URL without reloading the page.

Comment: Interesting.  Well, I'm unaware of any events that are generated by the use of pushState.

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/20544601/1362713

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find how to detect the whole URL change but this question learned me a few new things.

1. You can detect with `jQuery .on()` user click on the link that cases "page reload emulation" and use such event as "page reload event".
2. Now I know that function window.history.pushState() in html5 let you to change the URL without reloading the page.

Hope, it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old one, but I guess this can come handy to anybody who stumbles upon this post. The way is indeed the history API:

```
window.onpopstate = history.onpushstate = function(e) {//yourcode}
```

This will detect any change in the url of the page, very handy.

More info on history API *[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)*